# How Can I count the number of occurences for two items in a nested list

Tags: python, count, nested, conditional-statements

I have a nested list

```
a = [[1,'a','b'], [2,'c','d'], [3,'a','b']]
```

how can i count the number of occurrences that a & b appeared in the nested list?

in this case the answer shall be 2 times.

p.s. this is my first time post, so thanks for all the help.

Comment: Did you even try something or at least looked up the existing answers on Stack Overflow?

Comment: Hi, I looked up the forum, it seems that i cant find the right term for the search , as i imagine other people has asked this. i tried "nested count with conditions" but no luck.
I built a code that counts 1 item type, and its working fine, now am looking to count when specific two items match.

Comment: If you just copy paste the title of your question and add "python" to it and search, you will get so many answers.

Comment: but i want to count how many time two items appear, not 1 item.
in my case, i need to count how many times  'a' & 'b' appeared

Comment: Could you post what you have tried? At least the one you did that works for one element?

Answer (score 0):

You can test for inclusion in a list with

`'a' in some_list`

This will be true or false. You can make multiple tests with `and` (there are also some other ways that may be a little prettied):

`'a' in some_list and 'b' in some_list`

This will be true if *both* conditions are met. To do this for all the lists in your list you can use a list comprehension:

```
a_list = [[1,'a','b'], [2,'c','d'], [3,'a','b']]

['a' in x and 'b' in x for x in a_list]
```

This will return a list of boolean values, one for each item in your list:

```
[True, False, True]
```

When treated like numbers python treats `True` as `1` and `False` as `0`. This means you can just sum that list to get you count and have a solution in one line:

```
a_list = [[1,'a','b'], [2,'c','d'], [3,'a','b']]

sum(['a' in x and 'b' in x for x in a_list])
# 2
```